# Make people succeed vs make people successful

Tags: difference

I want to know the difference between these sentences.

> 1. A warm, kind heart makes people succeed.
> 2. A warm, kind heart makes people successful.

Comment: Basically the same meaning, the difference being 'successful' is an adjective describing the person, and 'succeed' being a verb.

Comment: To me, it’s the same meaning. From a style point of view, I’d choose the 2nd.

Comment: @JamesWirth You should make that an answer

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, the two sentences are basically interchangeable.

The difference is that 'successful' is an adjective describing the state of the person with a warm, kind heart.

On the contrary, 'succeed' is a verb and is the action of becoming successful.

So in essence the only difference is that 'makes people successful' describes the final state or character of the person who had the kind heart, but 'makes people succeed' empathizes the action of attaining success.